# Nested loops skipping over items in list

Tags: python

The objective I had was to remove all words in a list that contained letters from user input

```
import pandas as pd

filtered = ['d','dd','ddd','dddd','ddddd','dddddd']
filtered_lc = [x.lower() for x in filtered]

str = input("Input wrong letters (enter blank to skip): ")

for word in filtered_lc:
    for letter in str:
        if letter in word and word in filtered_lc:
            filtered_lc.remove(word)


df = pd.DataFrame(filtered_lc)
print("-----------------------\n", df)
```

Desired output should be nothing

Output I got:

```
-----------------------
         0
0      dd
1    dddd
2  dddddd
```

Could anyone explain why it is only processing for the 1st, 3rd and 5th word in the list please? Thank you

Comment: why do you use pandas to display the result, instead of print `filtered_lc` directly?

Comment: Removing an item from the list changes what you are iterating over in a way that isn't communicated to the iterator. Effectively, you have changed what is in the current position, but the iterator doesn't know that, and moves on to the *next* position without ever having seen the "new" current value.

Comment: (Holding off on an answer because there must be a relevant duplicate.)

Comment: `str` is a calss name in Python. Don't use it as a variable name!

Answer (score 1):

First of all rename the variable `str` to something else as it is already type in python.

Also, you are removing from the list you are itterating which can also cause problems.

Try:

```
import pandas as pd

filtered = ['d','dd','ddd','dddd','ddddd','dddddd']
filtered_lc = [x.lower() for x in filtered]

filtered_lc_cpy = filtered_lc.copy()

_str = input("Input wrong letters (enter blank to skip): ")

for word in filtered_lc_cpy:
    for letter in _str:
        if letter in word and word in filtered_lc:
            filtered_lc.remove(word)


df = pd.DataFrame(filtered_lc)
print("-----------------------\n", df)
```

Comment: You don't have to use a for loop to copy a list

Comment: `filtered_lc_copy = filtered_lc.copy()`

Comment: Well technically you can do `for word in filtered_lc.copy()` but it is not good to be understood by beginners, also I've corrected it.